# Problem with for loop while working with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

This afternoon I was practicing a bit with vuejs. Simply use axios to get some data. I succeeded in retrieving data. But then I encountered a problem with the for loop.

**If I do this**

```
<template></template>

<script>
export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                arr: []
            } 
        },
        created() {
            axios.get('url')
            .then(function(res) {
                for (var i = 0; i <= res.length; i++) {
                    if (true) {
                        // If i assign the value to the 'array' here, the for loop will stop
                        this.arr.push('something')
                        // I have also tried this.$data.arr
                    }
                }
            })
            .catch(err=>console.log(err));
        }
    }    
</script>
```

**So I changed a bit and it worked**

```
<script>

    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                arr: []
            } 
        },
        created() {
            var second_arr = []; // Defined a variable here
            axios.get('url')
            .then(function(res) {
                for (var i = 0; i <= res.length; i++) {
                    if (true) {
                        // Working with 'second_arr' variable instead of the 'arr' variable in the data 
                        second_arr.push = something; 
                    }
                }
            })
            .catch(err=>console.log(err));

            //then assign 'second_arr' to 'arr' in the data
            this.arr = second_arr;
        }
    }    
</script>
```

**The question is**

 1. In the first code, why does the loop only run once?

 2. I have tried to find out and found a few comments about 'scope'. So can someone explain more clearly to me? Thanks.

Comment: have you checked the length of `res` ? like console logged it?

Comment: @GBWDev yes, i have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code this in then function is undefined, you can use arrow funtion to bind this

```
.then((res) => {
                for (var i = 0; i <= res.length; i++) {
                    if (true) {
                        // If i assign the value to the 'array' here, the for loop will stop
                        this.arr.push('something')
                        // I have also tried this.$data.arr
                    }
                }
            })
```

like this

Answer (score 1):

All action must take place in `then` as axios do asychronous call, and scope `this` in function has another value:

```
var that = this;
var second_arr = []; // Defined a variable here
axios.get('url')
  .then(function(res) {
     for (var i = 0; i <= res.length; i++) {
        if (true) {
            second_arr.push = something; 
        }
     }
     that.arr = second_arr;
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your data are not in `response` but in `response.data`

[image]

As you can see when you `console.log(response.length)` console's returns `undefined` but when you `console.length(response.data.length)` it returns `1`

EDIT : In my exemple case, there's only one object in data, maybe in your case it will be more than 1